# É possível criar mais de um modulo java9(module-info) por projeto mavem no eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

Estou testando o sistema de módulos do java 9 e até o momento consegui criar um projeto no eclipse (maven ou java) e criar o modulo-info pela opção :
Botão direito no mouse no projeto + configure + criar module-info.

Porém se necessitar separar o projeto em vários módulos?
É possível fazer isso no mesmo projeto ou devo criar um projeto para cada modulo?
Se é possível criar vários módulos no mesmo projeto no eclipse como faze-lo?

Comment: Acho que você teria que usar um projeto por módulo e um módulo por projeto.

Comment: Acredito que isso va ser determinado pelos arquivos POM, cada POM ou cada projeto maven vai ter suas configs próprias, 1 pom == 1 config... voce pode ter mais de um projeto maven centralizado dentro de um projeto maior, cada qual com seu POM e seu config, e um projeto maior configurando tudo.(mas eu nao tenho certeza).